# Is it possible that $L$ is not totally ramified over $K$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $L$ be a totally ramified extension of the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Then there is an algebraic number $\alpha$ which is a root of an Eisenstein polynomial so that $$L=\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha).$$

Assume an intermediate field $K$ i.e., satisfying  $\mathbb{Q}_p \subset K \subset L$.

> Is it possible that $L$ is totally ramified over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ but not over $K$ ?

---

If we assume $K$ is a totally ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, does it help ?

In that case $K$ is totally ramified at every prime of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. On the other hand, $L$ is totally ramified at every  prime of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Here totally ramified means having the same residue field as $\Bbb{Q}_p$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I assume that all occuring fields are local, and that all extensions are finite.)

We have
$$f_{L \mid \mathbb{Q}_p} = f_{L \mid K} \cdot f_{K \mid \mathbb{Q}_p},$$
and $L \mid \mathbb{Q}_p$ being totally ramified means by definition that $f_{L \mid \mathbb{Q}_p} = 1$. Since the $f$'s are positive integers, this is possible only if $f_{L \mid K} =1$, thus if $L$ is totally ramified over $K$.